# Excel Search Range, Bring Back Row Content

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How I'm I able to search a range for a string and then bring back the row of where it was found

I'm using this formula below `=COUNTIF(rng,"*"&value&"*")>0` to see if its there and it works, but how do I bring back data? of what was found in that row

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand... a better explanation and maybe some screenshots of a specific example and desired result would help. However, I would probably assign each row an ID and then "bring back" any desired data using INDEX/MATCH formulas.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/position-of-first-partial-match

Comment: Its like index Match on but the range is not 1 column its is many ranges to search

Answer (score 0):

You can use AGGREGATE if looking in a two Dimensional range:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(D9:G17)/(D9:G17=B1),1)
```

For a partial match:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(D9:G17)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,D9:G17))),1)
```

[image]